# Populate the title attribute on truncated starred chat messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

Please populate the `title` attribute in the "star-bar" with the complete message of otherwise truncated starred chat messages.

`<li id="summary_123" data-time="456" style="display: block;"`**`title="..."`**`>...</li>`

[image: Truncated message]

[image: Complete message]

That's all.

Comment: Maybe only the omitted text would be even better.

Comment: @Deduplicator Perhaps, though I'd prefer not; I don't like how GitHub does it with commit messages; `Updated the comp...` -- `...ponents`

Comment: @Deduplicator Whoops, unintentional double-"p". It should be deduplicated.