# Why some posts on meta are "muted"?

Tags: support, questions, meta, ignored-tags

I just saw this in Meta's Questions page:

[image: screenshot]

Why [first question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276066/1207195) is *muted* or *deemphasized* like answers with score less or equal than -3?

- It's not because of score (it's +3).
- It's not because it has no answer (because other questions without answers are not and other questions with answers are *muted* too).
- It's not deleted.
- I don't have any favorite tag on meta so it should not be related to my own preferences.
- It's not a case because I see same behavior for many questions.

What's that? What should be highlighted or dimmed?

Comment: You don't have any ignored tags, right?

Comment: By chance, do you ignore the chat or feature-request tags?

Comment: I just tested this by ignoring the discussion tag. You at some point set one of the tags on the question to ignored. You mention in your question that you don't have favorite tags, but you probably have ignored tags.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I just looked at [your profile preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and saw this:

[image: Ignored Tags: feature-request support]

So yeah - when you tell the system to gray out questions with certain tags, questions with those tags will appear gray.

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember I did it and actually I was interested on that tags. I guess someone here is so stupid to add to "ignored" instead of "favorites" (a d that one it's me)

Comment: I check my ignored tags occasionally just to make sure I didn't accidentally ignore one, or ignored one when I was in a sour mood one day.

Comment: [The first rule of Tautology Club is the first rule of Tautology Club.](http://xkcd.com/703/)